# What happens if you subtract two uint256 values whose answer is supposed to be negative?

Tags: solidity, math

I tried it with

```
    uint256 a = 3;
    uint256 b = 6;
    log(a - b); // my own function
```

And the logged output was a huge number. Obviously that's a bug. So how do you deal with this situation? check if a > b return a - b, else 0? Or (dumb question incoming) is it safe to assume that subtracting a big uint from a small uint will result in 0 somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

solidity (prior to version 0.8.x) doesn't check for over/underflows. That means that if you're if you're trying to set it to less than 0 (or more than (2^256 -1) it's going to wrap around (0-1 = 2^256-1 and (2^256-1) +1 = 0 ). The way we used to deal with this prior to 0.8 is to use the `SafeMath` library, which does pretty much what you've described.

Comment: At 0.8.x and above, do Solidity developers still use `SafeMath`, or do they just rely on the runtime's over/underflow check?

Comment: It depends, ive seen `SafeMath` being used in 0.8+ but it's not mandatory anymore, in fact in most contracts where i see it it's just a waste of gas. Though SafeMath also have `try` variants of the operators, which returns instead of reverting on overflows. This can be useful for some applications.